# Capitalize first letter of each word in a selection using Vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace, find, capitalize

In Vim, I know we can use `~` to capitalize a single char (as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126500/how-do-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-a-word-in-vim)), but is there a way to capitalize the first letter of each word in a selection using Vim?

For example, if I would like to change this

```
hello world from stack overflow
```

to

```
Hello World From Stack Overflow
```

how should I do it in Vim?

Comment: Can also be done with [sed](https://superuser.com/a/749174/86708)

Comment: For anyone else who lands here but wants to capitalize the first letter in a VERTICAL selection covering multiple lines, just do `Ctrl+V`, make your vertical selection to select the first letters, then type `~` and every first letter in each line will now be capitalized.

Comment: I'm trying to find an answer that improves on `noremap <M-c> ~w` (Alt+c to capitalize whatever is under the cursor then move on to the next word). I find it easier in practice to control doing it interactively rather than batched.

Comment: It took me 14 years to get this much loved XEmacs functionality over to Vim. If only I'd not been afraid of Vimscript all these years.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You can use the following substitution:

```
s/\<./\u&/g
```

- `\<` matches the start of a word
- `.` matches the first character of a word
- `\u` tells Vim to uppercase the following character in the substitution string `(&)`
- `&` means substitute whatever was matched on the left-hand side
- `g` means substitute all matches, not only the first

Comment: I just had to do this and used a macro that I over-repeated and I knew there had to be some better way but I never though of regex.  This is great. Thanks.

Comment: to do it in entire file `%s/\<./\u&/g`

Comment: Is there a non-regex solution? Emacs has [`upcase-initials-region`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/44189/5224).

Answer (score 74):

`:help case` says:

```
To turn one line into title caps, make every first letter of a word
uppercase:
    : s/\v<(.)(\w*)/\u\1\L\2/g
```

Explanation:

```
:                      # Enter ex command line mode.

space                  # The space after the colon means that there is no
                       # address range i.e. line,line or % for entire
                       # file.

s/pattern/result/g     # The overall search and replace command uses
                       # forward slashes.  The g means to apply the
                       # change to every thing on the line. If there
                       # g is missing, then change just the first match
                       # is changed.
```

The pattern portion has this meaning:

```
\v                     # Means to enter very magic mode.
<                      # Find the beginning of a word boundary.
(.)                    # The first () construct is a capture group.
                       # Inside the () a single ., dot, means match any
                       #  character.
(\w*)                  # The second () capture group contains \w*. This
                       # means find one or more word characters. \w* is
                       # shorthand for [a-zA-Z0-9_].
```

The result or replacement portion has this meaning:

```
\u                     # Means to uppercase the following character.
\1                     # Each () capture group is assigned a number
                       # from 1 to 9. \1 or back slash one says use what
                       # I captured in the first capture group.
\L                     # Means to lowercase all the following characters.
\2                     # Use the second capture group
```

Result:

```
ROPER STATE PARK
Roper State Park
```

An alternate to the very magic mode:

```
: % s/\<\(.\)\(\w*\)/\u\1\L\2/g
# Each capture group requires a backslash to enable their meta
# character meaning i.e. "\(\)" versus "()".
```

Comment: This was the most interesting answer to me.  I'd never seen the very magic mode.  I thought I'd document the answer after I understood the answer.

Comment: Additionally, this answer handles all lower case, all upper case, or mixed case strings.

Comment: I used \S instead of \w for non-ascii characters: `s/\v<(.)(\S*)/\u\1\L\2/g` :-)

Answer (score 15):

The Vim Tips Wiki has a [TwiddleCase mapping](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switching_case_of_characters#Twiddle_case) that toggles the visual selection to lower case, UPPER CASE, and Title Case.

If you add the `TwiddleCase` function to your `.vimrc`, then you just visually select the desired text and press the tilde character `~` to cycle through each case.

Answer (score 3):

***Option 1. --*** This mapping maps the key `q` to capitalize the letter at the cursor position, and then it moves to the start of the next word:

:map q gUlw

To use this, put the cursor at the start of the line and hit `q` once for each word to capitalize the first letter.  If you want to leave the first letter the way it is, hit `w` instead to move to the next word.

***Option 2. --*** This mappings maps the key `q` to invert the case of the letter at the cursor position, and then it moves to the start of the next word:

```
:map q ~w
```

To use this, put the cursor at the start of the line hit `q` once for each word to invert the case of the first letter.  If you want to leave the first letter the way it is, hit `w` instead to move to the next word.

***Unmap mapping. --*** To unmap (delete) the mapping assigned to the `q` key:

```
:unmap q
```

Comment: Why a mapping and not an actual macro? `qq~wq` and replay with `@q` followed by `@@` ?

Comment: `gUlw` seems to jump to the 2nd character of the next word, and no matter how well I think I know vimscript I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try This regex ..

```
s/ \w/ \u&/g
```

Comment: I liked the answer with the use of the `&` but it does not work if  your string string is mixed case to begin with or all uppercase to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the very useful [`vim-titlecase`](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-titlecase) plugin for this.

Comment: Thanks. Smart Title Case works well for Sublime Text as well. https://github.com/mattstevens/sublime-titlecase

Answer (score 1):

To restrict the modification to the visual selection we have to use something like:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\<.\%V/\u&/g

\%V ............... see help for this
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do what you want on a random string and retain some control of words that you generally do not want capitalized (eg: articles like of/and) is to use `~` to change the case of the first word and then `w.` to select and change each word in turn, bearing in mind you can skip the **`.`** (repeat char) if you don't want to capitalize a particular word.

Answer (score 0):

The following mapping causes <kbd>g~</kbd> to "title case" selected text:

```
vnoremap g~ "tc<C-r>=substitute(@t, '\v<(.)(\S*)', '\u\1\L\2', 'g')<CR><Esc>
```