# How to capitalize first letter of every word using sed in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, sed, pipe, capitalization

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of every word in a string using the following sed command, but it's not working:

```
 echo "my string" | sed 's/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g'
```

Output:

```
 my string
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use regex with sed (or equivalent unix command line tool) to fix title case in LaTeX headings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909531/how-can-i-use-regex-with-sed-or-equivalent-unix-command-line-tool-to-fix-title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been addressed:  [Uppercasing First Letter of Words Using SED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538676/uppercasing-first-letter-of-words-using-sed)

I get the correct behavior with GNU sed, but not with the standard BSD sed that ships with OS X. I think the \u "regular expression" is a GNU thing. How about "port install gsed"?

Edit: if you **really** want to use BSD sed, which I would not recommend (because the command becomes very ugly), then you can do the following: 
`sed -E "s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)a:\1A:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)b:\1B:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)c:\1C:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)d:\1D:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)e:\1E:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)f:\1F:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)g:\1G:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)h:\1H:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)i:\1I:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)j:\1J:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)k:\1K:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)l:\1L:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)m:\1M:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)n:\1N:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)o:\1O:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)p:\1P:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)q:\1Q:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)r:\1R:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)s:\1S:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)t:\1T:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)u:\1U:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)v:\1V:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)w:\1W:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)x:\1X:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)y:\1Y:g; s:([^[:alnum:]_]|^)z:\1Z:g;"`

Comment: Unfortunately, installing a gsed is not a viable option. I'm writing a script that will be used mainly by other OSX users.

Comment: Then I think sed is not the right tool for the job here, since you won't get capitalization without GNU extensions, you might want to try perl for example (don't know about awk).  If you really *need* to do it with BSD sed, then you have to do it letter by letter...

Comment: I've reached the same conclusion. I ended up using a bash for loop and tr.

Comment: @Ares Every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach (google it). Just use awk since text manipulation is what it was invented to do.

Answer (score 8):

Given your sample input, this will work in any awk:

```
$ echo 'my string' | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)} 1'
My String
```

If that doesn't do what you really want then edit your question to show some more truly representative sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sed solution that works on OSX:

```
echo 'my string
ANOTHER STRING
tHiRd StRiNg' | sed -En '
y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/
:loop
h
s/^(.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])?([a-z]).*$/\2/
t next
b end
:next
y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
G
s/^(.+)\n(.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])?[a-z](.*)$/\2\1\3/
t loop
:end
p
'

Output:
My String
Another String
Third String
```

The sed command works as follows:

1. sed inputs a line, and the first y command transforms all uppercase letters to lowercase.
2. The commands from :loop to t loop form a loop that executes once for
       each word in the current line, capitalizing the first letter of each word.
3. When there are no more words to capitalize for the current line, the p command prints the line, and sed inputs the next line.

Here is how the loop works:

1. The h command saves the line as it currently stands to the hold
   space.
2. The first s command looks for the first letter of the first
   non-capitalized word. If such a word is found, the s command saves
   its first letter to the pattern space, and the t command branches to
   the :next label. If such a word is not found, which indicates that
   there are no more words to capitalize, the b command is executed
   instead, branching to the :end label to print out and complete the
   processing of the current line.
3. If a word needing capitalizing was found, execution resumes at the
   :next label, and the y command transforms the first letter, which is now in the pattern space, from lowercase to uppercase.
4. The G command appends the non-transformed version of the current
   line from the hold space to the end of the pattern space.
5. The second s command reconstructs the current line, replacing the first letter of the word currently being processed with its capitalized version.
6. The t command branches to the :loop label to look for the next word
   needing capitalization.

Execution speed testing revealed that the current sed approach executes at approximately the same speed as the awk solution submitted by Ed Morton.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
echo "my string" | sed -r 's/\b(.)/\u\1/g'
```

Comment: I am running this on OSX. I'm getting "sed: illegal option -- r"

Comment: on OSX use -E (I guess)

Comment: sed: 1: "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g": \1 not defined in the RE

Comment: It may not work in OSX (not tested), but it works super-fine in Bash on Mint. Thank you, this was what I was looking for.

Comment: `-r` is the option to enable EREs in old versions of GNU sed only. In recent versions of GNU sed and BSD sed you can use `-E` to enable EREs. You aren't using EREs though so you don't need `-E` or `-r` and I doubt if `\u` will work in any sed except GNU sed.

Comment: Without `-r` or `-E` the `(` `)` need to be escaped